# returning multiple json via php

Tags: php, json

I need to retrieve from my db a list of users, that can have the same name. I'm having trouble do transform the result of my query to a json.

If I was going to retrieve only one result, the code will work, but since I started to use `LIKE` it started to fail.

php code:

```
<?php


$q = $_POST['q'];

require('connect.php');

$i = 0;

$sql="SELECT `_nome`, `_endereco`, `_telefone`, `_imgstring`, `_dtAcesso`, `_descricao`, `_fkIdUser` FROM `tbvisitantes` WHERE _nome LIKE CONCAT ('%',?,'%')";
$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $q);


if ($stmt){
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($rName, $rEndereco, $rTelefone, $rImgString, $rDtAcesso, $rDescricao, $rFkIdUser);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch_array()){

$json_output = array('name' => $rName, 'address' => $rEndereco, 'tel' => $rTelefone, 'imgString' => $rImgString, 'dtAcesso' => $rDtAcesso, 'descricao' => $rDescricao, 'fkIdUser' => $rFkIdUser);

echo json_encode($json_output);

}

$stmt->close();

}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

The script that receives the result:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'getuser.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {q: str},
success: function(jsonString){

$vIndex = '<input class="vInput"></input>';

$($cadContent).appendTo('#cadContent');

var json = $.parseJSON(jsonString);

var jsonLenght = Object.keys(jsonString).length;


$.each(json, function(index, el) {

$($vIndex).attr('id', index).val(el).appendTo('#txtHint');


});


}
})
.done(function() {
console.log("success");
})
.fail(function(xhr) {

alert("An error ocurred:" + xhr.status + xhr.statusText);

console.log('failed');
})
.always(function() {
console.log("complete");
});


}
```

I think that my problem could by in the construction of my JSON, but i don't now how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't echo the multiple response in json. You have to combine the the response into one array and then you have to echo the response.

This below snippet will helpful to you,

Server page:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_array()){

   $json_output[] = array('name' => $rName, 'address' => $rEndereco, 'tel' => $rTelefone, 'imgString' => $rImgString, 'dtAcesso' => $rDtAcesso, 'descricao' => $rDescricao, 'fkIdUser' => $rFkIdUser);

}
echo json_encode($json_output);
```

In Ajax Page:

```
// your success callback handler
function handler( response ) {
  // execute code for object 1
  doStuff(response[0] );
  // execute code for object 2
  doOtherStuff( response[1] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the rows into a single JSON array:

```
if ($stmt){
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->bind_result($rName, $rEndereco, $rTelefone, $rImgString, $rDtAcesso, $rDescricao, $rFkIdUser);
  $rows = array();

  while ($row = $stmt->fetch_array()){

    $json_output = array('name' => $rName, 'address' => $rEndereco, 'tel' => $rTelefone, 'imgString' => $rImgString, 'dtAcesso' => $rDtAcesso, 'descricao' => $rDescricao, 'fkIdUser' => $rFkIdUser);
    $rows[] = $json_output;
  }
  echo json_encode($rows);
}
```